# How to compare mm/dd/yyyy with month only in SQL Server database using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

My data is saved in this format `mm/dd/yyyy`... and I want to compare my data with month only....I mean I want to show all data with respect to that month selected by datetimepicker.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Coregen\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\piechart\piechart\sale.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Tab_n WHERE Date='" + this.dateTimePicker1.Value + "'"; //
cmd.Connection = con;

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);

BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = dt;

dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
sda.Update(dt);

con.Close();
```

Comment: Your date is in string format in your DB? Datepicker returns your `DateTime` type?

Comment: What is the data type of the column?  Is it varchar or datetime?

Comment: Unless you plan on using this application for one year only, shouldn't you use month and year. All dates except February 29th occur every year (unless you're using the Mayan calendar which ended in 2012)?

Comment: Use a date data type in your database with a parameterised query

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something along these lines :

```
 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Column_1, Column_2 FROM Tab_n WHERE DATEPART(Month,Date) ='" + this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Month + "'";
```

You can simplify this by using `SQLParameter` :

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_Of_Something",this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Month);
```

**Edit** : 
Since you want to compare year too, you will have to add another `where` condition. This will again make use of the `DATEPART` function.

*Since I presume by now you must have taken up on the suggestion of using parameterized queries, the following addendum is answered with that approach in mind.*

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Column_1, Column_2 FROM Tab_n WHERE DATEPART(Month,Date) = @DatePicker_Month AND DATEPART(Year,Date) = @DatePicker_Year";
```

You will have two parameters in this case :

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DatePicker_Month",this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Month);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DatePicker_Year",this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Year);
```

This, for example, will allow you to fetch results for the 5th month (*specified by datepart_month variable*) for the year 2016 (*specified by datepart_year variable*).

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thanks allot for the help,but i want to compare year too..sorry i forgot to mention...can u please help me in this way

Answer (score 1):

I think using `BETWEEN` in your query is the best solution. First you find start and end of the month dates and then you put them inside `BETWEEN` operator:

```
// get DatePicker selected year and month
int year = dateTimePicker1.Value.Year;
int month = dateTimePicker1.Value.Month;

// start from the first day of the month
int startDay = 1;
// find the last day of selected month
int endDay = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);

DateTime startDate = new DateTime(year, month, startDay);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(year, month, endDay);

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Coregen\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\piechart\piechart\sale.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Tab_n WHERE Date BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate";
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", startDate);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", endDate);

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);

BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = dt;

dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
sda.Update(dt);

con.Close();
```